# Decompose relation into BCNF form

Tags: relational-database, database-normalization, bcnf

Suppose we have

`R(ABCDE)` and functional dependencies: `{AB -> C, B -> C, C -> D}`, convert this into BCNF.

I see that the candidate key for `R` is `ABE` so this is clearly not in BCNF already.

To decompose, I created these relations:

```
R1(ABC)
R2(BC)
R3(CD)
R4(ABE)
```

Does this work?

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--you may find mistakes that make your question unnecessary & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an algorithm allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went right or wrong & we don't want to rewite your textbook. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. So you tell us why it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the functional dependencies given are a cover of the functional dependencies holding on R, applying the so-called “analysis” algorithm produces the following decomposition:

```
R2 (ABE)
R3 (CD)
R4 (BC)
```

We start by considering a minimal cover of the dependencies. This is:

```
B → C
C → D
```

(since in AB → C we can note that A is estraneous, since we have already that B → C).

So, since B → C violates the BCNF, we decompose R in two relations:

```
R1 (BCD), with candidate key B
R2 (ABE), with candidate key ABE
```

In the second relation there are no non-trivial functional dependency, so we leave it as is, while in R1 the only candidate key is B, so C → D violates the BCNF and we decompose it in:

```
R3 (CD)
R4 (BC)
```

so the final decomposition is R2, R3 and R4. Note that this decomposition preserves the functional dependencies (not always this is possible with this algorithm).

Comment: > Note that this decomposition preserves the functional dependencies (not always this is possible with this algorithm).

Thanks a bunch! Can you tell me how this is true? The functional dependency `AB -> C` has disappeared?

Comment: @seq, If you join the decomposed relations, AB → C can be derived by B → C. In general many dependencies can be derived from others. For this reason is convenient to find a minimal (or canonical) cover befor applying the normalization algorithms.